# Optimize Distance Calculation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, distance, geo

I am trying to optimize the below query in BigQuery.

```
  Table1 has ~400K rows
  Table2 has 34M rows
```

I have to map each ID in Table1 with the closest Zipcode in Table2.

Both Table1 and Table2 Have Latitude and Longitude Data

```
WITH
tmp1 AS (
SELECT
 ID, latitude, longitude 
 FROM `Table1`),

tmp2 AS (
SELECT
  CAST(ZipCode AS string) AS ZipCode ,lat,lon
  FROM `Table2` )

 SELECT
 AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<ID STRING,ZipCode STRING, distance int64>(ID,
  ZipCode,
  CAST(ST_DISTANCE(tmp1.point,
      tmp2.point) AS int64))
  ORDER BY
  ST_DISTANCE(tmp1.point,
  tmp2.point)
  LIMIT
   1)[
  OFFSET
  (0)]
  FROM 
  (
  SELECT
 ID,ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude,latitude) point
  FROM tmp1) tmp1
  CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT
 ZipCode, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point
  FROM tmp2) tmp2
```

Will appreciate any help on this!

Comment: do you have any issues with the query you already have?

Comment: It is taking a lot of time. The query ran for more than 30 minutes but still no output. I guess because it is cross joining all 400k records with 34M rows in Table2. I am trying to see if there is a faster way to do it by adding constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery can very efficiently do spatial join, matching items across two tables that are within specific distance of each other. But you need to know that specific distance, or try several ones until you update all the points.

This post discusses it in more details:
https://medium.com/@mentin/nearest-neighbor-in-bigquery-gis-7d50ebd5d63

You can automate it using BigQuery scripting, here is an idea, although it discussed a slightly different problem, a nearest geometry to a single point:
https://medium.com/@mentin/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `GROUP BY ID` at the very end of your query.
I think this can contribute to slowness as well as all those CASTs ...

Try below version

```
#standardSQL
WITH tmp1 AS (
  SELECT ID, ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude) point
  FROM `Table1`
), tmp2 AS (
  SELECT CAST(ZipCode AS string) AS ZipCode, ST_GEOGPOINT(lon, lat) point
  FROM `Table2`
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(
  STRUCT(ID, ZipCode, distance)
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 1
)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM (
  SELECT ID, ZipCode, ST_DISTANCE(tmp1.point, tmp2.point) AS distance
  FROM tmp1, tmp2
)
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks but the query has been running for more than an hour. Can we add any constraints for it run faster?

Comment: sure. that depends on your business logic. for example you can add condition of being within same zip code or county or state

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if BigQuery had st_nearestneighbors function, which would just compute K closest objects (in this case K=1) without having to compute expensive cross-join and st_distance...

Comment: I think, that is where [k-means clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create#training_a_k-means_model]) can be used first and than have clusters as a constraint